# Getting a value of a dynamic class and dynamic property

Tags: php, eval, dynamic-class, dynamic-properties

Is it possible to get the value of a instance variable that is a class and the value needed to get is just a string?  I'm getting strings that are "$user->Prop" lets say, and I want to eval() this string to get the value, but it seems the eval function doesn't know about $user even though it is an instance variable.

```
$user->Prop = 3;
$a = "user->Prop";
$val = eval($$a); //how to get 3 with this string?
```

I know I can do

```
$prop = "prop";
$user->$prop;
```

and get 3, but in this case I'm trying to only pass in the variable I want to test and get the value in short.

Comment: what does your class look like ?
I think what you are trying to do should be simpler than this.

Comment: it would be far too much code to show, I did summarize what is happening in the code snip above.

Comment: so I am assuming $user is an object of the user class. Something like $user = new User(). if Prop is declared as public in the user class then you should be able to get the value by doing something like: var_dump($user->Prop)

Comment: yes, but I only have a value of string(11)"$user->Prop" and want to eval to 3 in this case.

Comment: ah, it turns out the eval function will return a value, but I must use return so in this case if I'm receiving "$user->Prop" I have to do $a = "/$user->Prop"; $val = eval("return $a;");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` does not return result of evaluated, if you want to store property value in `$val`, you have to include it in evaluated string:

```
$a = 'user->prop';
$eval = '$val = $'.$a.';';

eval($eval);
var_dump($val);
```

Comment: best solution, I've put a method to eval the value by putting return in the string, this got me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This won't work because you can't represent the `->` dynamically.

```
$user->Prop = 3;
$a = "user->Prop";
$val = ${$a};
```

But you can do this:

```
$user->Prop = 3;
$a = "user";
$b = "Prop";
$val = ${$a}->$b;
```

Comment: @tlenss ahhh. nice catch.  Started up my Wamp and double checked.  Edited my answer to correct your find.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I have a string(11)"$user->Prop" and it is stored in $a what I need to do is:

```
$val = eval("return $a;");
```

need to read the docs more closely...good to write about it I guess though.